# How do I remove www from site urls under unicorn web server stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, engineyard

I have a rails application hosted on engineyard cloud using unicorn web server stack. I am trying to remove www from the site url but still have no luck. I used to provide RewriteRule in .htaccess for my apache application but I am not sure about unicorn/nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will redirect any requests for http://www.abc.de to http://abc.de:

```
server {
  server_name www.abc.de;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://abc.de/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  server_name abc.de;
  # rest of the config goes here
}
```

You'd normally put this in your vhost config at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/site_name`; the equivalent on EngineYard appears to be `/etc/nginx/servers/app_name/custom.conf`, but don't quote me on that.